# Экспертная система

Tags: php, wordpress, искусственный-интеллект

Как связать учебную среду с экспертной системой, какими софты юзать (например, PHP + Clips, Python + Prolog), желательно состыковать вордпрес с какой нибудь экспертной системой.

**Обновление**

Учебную среду планирую на wordpress заклепать (это онлайн курсы, с возможностью проставлять оценки, имеющая свою учебную литературу, обучающие группы и т.п.), под экспертной системой clips (от англ. C Language Integrated Production System) —программная среда для разработки экспертных систем.

Comment: Что вы понимаете под учебной средой и под экспертной системой? "clips" это IDE Eclipse?

Comment: ок, стало понятнее. Но все равно вопрос очень обширный, сложно на него ответить в общем виде. Вы можете например нарисовать архитектуру проекта в виде схемы и тогда можно будет что-то конкретное оценивать. Если так сделаете, добавьте метку [tag:инспекция-кода]